# Ionic angularjs button glow on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic app wherein I have following requirement:

[image]

On clicking ***Start*** button the buttons starts glowing in random order for few predefined milliseconds and after it stops user is supposed to click the buttons in order they blinked within next 3 seconds. If he succeeds then Level 1 is completed.

So far, I simply have html buttons with a css that makes button glow as seen in the attached screenshot. How can I implement some method in my controller which will trigger glowing effect and handle all these time intervals? $interval seems like an option for the later one.

**My css:**

```
.large_button {
  line-height: 10vh !important;
  width: 50%;
  }

.start-button {
  line-height: 5vh !important;
  width: 15%;
  }  

.button {
  background-color: #004A7F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glowing1 {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing2 {
  0% { background-color: #228B22; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #228B22; }
  50% { background-color: #7CFC00; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #7CFC00; }
  100% { background-color: #228B22; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #228B22; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing3 {
  0% { background-color: #CCCC00; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CCCC00; }
  50% { background-color: #FFFF00; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FFFF00; }
  100% { background-color: #CCCC00; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CCCC00; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing4 {
  0% { background-color: #0000FF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0000FF; }
  50% { background-color: #1E90FF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #1E90FF; }
  100% { background-color: #0000FF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0000FF; }
}

#button1 {
  -webkit-animation: glowing1 1000ms infinite;
}

#button2 {
    color: #000000;
  -webkit-animation: glowing2 1000ms infinite;

}

#button3 {
    color: #B8860B;
  -webkit-animation: glowing3 1000ms infinite;

}

#button4 {
  -webkit-animation: glowing4 1000ms infinite;

}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">


    <div padding align="center">
      <h2>Please select a button!</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- First row of buttons -->
    <div class="row">

      <!-- First column -->  
      <div class="col col-50 col-offset-10" style="padding-top:1cm;">
        <button type="submit" class="button large_button" id="button1">Click me!</button>
      </div>

      <!-- First column -->
      <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top:1cm;">
        <button type="submit" class="button large_button" id="button2">Click me!</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <!-- First column -->  
      <div class="col col-50 col-offset-10" style="padding-top:1cm;">
        <button type="submit" class="button large_button" id="button3">Click me!</button>
      </div>

      <!-- First column -->
      <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top:1cm;">
        <button type="submit" class="button large_button" id="button4">Click me!</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div align="center">
      <button class="button button-bar button-dark start-button" ng-click="startAnimation()">Start</button>
    </div>

    <div align="left" style="padding-left:5cm;padding-top:1cm;">
      <h1>Level 1 
      <i class="icon ion-android-checkbox"></i></h1>
    </div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Also can I optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

I used ng-class on all the buttons to apply css on-click of **Start** button. I used *$interval* directive to activate glowing for 2 milliseconds.

**My HTML**

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">


    <div padding align="center">
      <h2>Please select a button!</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- First row of buttons -->
    <div class="row">

      <!-- First column -->  
      <div class="col col-50 col-offset-10" style="padding-top:1cm;">
        <button type="submit" class="button large_button" ng-class="{'button1': isActive}" id="button1">Click me!</button>
      </div>

      <!-- First column -->
      <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top:1cm;">
        <button type="submit" class="button large_button" ng-class="{'button2': isActive}" id="button2">Click me!</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <!-- First column -->  
      <div class="col col-50 col-offset-10" style="padding-top:1cm;">
        <button type="submit" class="button large_button" ng-class="{'button3': isActive}" id="button3">Click me!</button>
      </div>

      <!-- First column -->
      <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top:1cm;">
        <button type="submit" class="button large_button" ng-class="{'button4': isActive}" id="button4">Click me!</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div align="center">
      <button class="button button-bar button-dark start-button" ng-click="start()" >Start</button>
    </div>

    <div align="left" style="padding-left:5cm;padding-top:1cm;">
      <h1>Level 1 
      <i class="icon ion-android-checkbox"></i>
      </h1>
    </div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**My CSS**

```
.large_button {
  line-height: 10vh !important;
  width: 50%;
  }

.start-button {
  line-height: 5vh !important;
  width: 15%;
  }  

.button {
  background-color: #004A7F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glowing1 {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing2 {
  0% { background-color: #228B22; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #228B22; }
  50% { background-color: #7CFC00; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #7CFC00; }
  100% { background-color: #228B22; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #228B22; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing3 {
  0% { background-color: #CCCC00; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CCCC00; }
  50% { background-color: #FFFF00; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FFFF00; }
  100% { background-color: #CCCC00; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CCCC00; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing4 {
  0% { background-color: #0000FF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0000FF; }
  50% { background-color: #1E90FF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #1E90FF; }
  100% { background-color: #0000FF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0000FF; }
}

.button1 {
  -webkit-animation: glowing1 1000ms infinite;
}

.button2 {
    color: #000000;
  -webkit-animation: glowing2 1000ms infinite;

}

.button3 {
    color: #B8860B;
  -webkit-animation: glowing3 1000ms infinite;

}

.button4 {
  -webkit-animation: glowing4 1000ms infinite;

}
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {

    $scope.Timer = null;

    $scope.start = function(){

      $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;

      $scope.Timer = $interval(function(){

        $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
        $interval.cancel($scope.Timer);

      }, 2000);

    }

})
```